# Remove a secondary from a mongo replica set without triggering re-election?

Tags: replication, mongodb, replica-set

I had to add a new secondary node to my replica set yesterday so that I could do maintenance on another secondary node.  Now that the maintenance is complete, I'd like to remove one of the secondaries to return to my original configuration.

The problem is that I've seen that the primary node always steps down to a secondary for a few moments while a vote is performed.  That's all well and good, but is there a way I can make that not happen?  I'm under a pretty heavy write-load and I don't want to fail any writes.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no way to prevent an election when you remove a node, hence the note in the [remove command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.remove/#rs.remove). Generally I would recommend only doing a reconfiguration during a maintenance window unless it is an addition (which should not impact anything as long as all nodes are healthy).

This is something of a "better safe than sorry approach" for the general case because there are some scenarios where you have to have an election and others where an election really is not needed.  Hence there is now [SERVER-11564](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11564) where the proposed non-election scenarios are being tracked as a future improvement.